# Which of the two is correct? (A) Having a bad reputation … actually bad. (B) Having a bad reputation … being bad

Tags: adverbs

Which of the two is correct?

(A) Having a bad reputation is worse than being actually bad.
(B) Having a bad reputation is worse than actually being bad.

It is the placement of "actually" within the sentence I am unsure about. They both sound fine to me, but if I was forced to choose one of them then it would be (A).

Is there a general rule that will let me resolve questions of this sort myself, without resorting to this web site? I would appreciate whatever guidance anyone is able to give.

Comment: I find the second more idiomatic.

Comment: They're both grammatical and they mean the same things. We don't know what "a bad reputation" or "being bad" mean in context, because no context is given. "Being bad" is what you say children are doing when they're too loud, so there are contexts where this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your two examples are fine and are just slightly different.

"actually being bad" confirms the state of being bad.

"being actually bad" highlights the bad and to me suggests a worse behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different implication

> being actually bad [as opposed to being good]

vs

> actually being bad [as opposed to just having a reputation]